# Windows 7 firewall not blocking ping requests

Tags: windows-7, firewall, ping

I have ICMPv4/6 blocked in my Windows 7 firewall. No matter what I do, my computer can still be pinged. The rule is enabled, etc. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you pinging your computer from your LAN or from the WAN? Do you have ICMP blocked for both? You can also try running `netsh firewall set icmpsetting type = all mode = disabled`

Comment: Using LAN, and computer is still responding to pings. Even when using your method.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Windows 7 and this may be something obvious you've already done. [Here's a possible answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-block-ping-icmp-with-firewall-windows-7-please/dc78a034-0a4c-412c-ae83-da9d9d972701) for you for Windows 7:

> What you've probably done is configure your network type as either a
>   home network or a work network which allows your machines to somewhat
>   talk to each other.  A quick way to change this is to right-click on
>   your network icon (in the taskbar) and choose "Open Network and
>   Sharing Center".  Here you will see your network and more importantly
>   the type of network it's configured as.  If you click on your network
>   type and change it to "Public network" it will make the firewall more
>   secure and prevent things like ICMP.
>
> The other option you have is to configure your firewall rules
>   manually.  In the same window (Network and Sharing Center) you will
>   see a link on the left towards the bottom which is labeled "Windows
>   Firewall".  If you go in the and then click advanced on the left hand
>   side the whole world of firewall rules opens up to you and you can do
>   all kinds of creative things.
>
> Be careful, you could make things "too" secure.  If you do however
>   there is the option to revert things back to default...

Answer (score 1):

If your router doesn’t support blocking ping, there is nothing you can do on your computer because your router automatically respond to ping request.